# How can I alias specific members of a class with 'using static'?

Tags: c#

I like C# 6's [`using static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#static-modifier) feature:

```cs
using static System.Math;

// ...

var result = Abs(-100);     // instead of Math.Abs(-100);
```

But that clutters IntelliSense with everything else in the `Math` type. Most of the time I just need a few members of that type.

Is it possible to alias a specific member, rather than the whole class? Something like:

```cs
using static Abs = System.Math.Abs;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done, but I found an interesting conversion on [the language repo](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/5925), with this workaround (a facade):

`GlobalAliases.cs`:

```cs
global using static System.MyMath;
global using static System.MyConsole;

namespace System;

internal static class MyMath
{
    public static decimal Abs(decimal value) => Math.Abs(value);
    // other members of interest...
}

internal static class MyConsole
{
    public static void Log(string? s) => Console.WriteLine(s);  // rename!
    // other members of interest...
}
```

`SomeClass.cs`:

```cs
var result = Abs(-100);
Log(result);
```

Comment: I would argue that you would not want such classes to be `public`, as it's an internal utility class that external consumers of your assembly (if any) should not see. Like extension classes, exposing these things to the general public should be done cautiously.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Very good point, and I agree. Updated.

Comment: I just want to point out that you're not forced to use `global using` here (unless you benefit from it). Even before C# 10 (i.e., before `global using` directives), you could just add `using static System.MyMath;` and `using static System.MyConsole;` at the top of the file where needed, and it would work the same.